# How to change yii 2 form fields dynamically

Tags: yii2

I need to show different form fields for different selections on a dynamic selection of a select box. Basically I want to dynamically change some fields of a form. How to do this in Yii? Or should I write the entire functionality in javascript itself?

Answer (score 0):

There are some widgets out there which can help you as a base for our need. Give it a check in example to this one: https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform